# get and write line with some number

Tags: java, swing

I need to get certain line from text component with multiline support. So it either `JTextArea` or `JTextPane`.

How to get line 1 , 2 or .. etc? For example get `line3` from text below

```
line1
line2
line3
line4
```

And is it possible to set another value for some line? For examp. set `lineNew` instead of `line2`

```
line1
lineNew
line3
line4
```

Is there any way?

Comment: Read the whole text and replace it as a whole text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To grab the text in a `JTextComponent`, use the `getText()` method which will return a `String`.

Then to get the lines, split the string on `\n`.

```
JTextArea txt = new JTextArea("line1\nline2\nline3\nline4");
String s = txt.getText();
String[] lines = s.split("\n");
// now to access the second line, use lines[1]
```

Now if you want to modify the text, you can use the `setText(String)` method.

```
txt.setText("something else");
```

There are also a few other methods that you can use to change the text like `insert(String,int)`, `append(String)`, and `replaceRange(String,int,int)`. All of this is documented in the [javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextArea.html).

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`JTextArea#replaceRange`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextArea.html#replaceRange%28java.lang.String,%20int,%20int%29) to replace a certain line.

For retrieving a certain line I am not completely sure, but I think that the [`JTextArea#getLineCount`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextArea.html#getLineCount%28%29), [`JTextArea#getLineStartOffset`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextArea.html#getLineStartOffset%28int%29), [`JtextArea#getLineEndOffset`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextArea.html#getLineEndOffset%28int%29) should allow you to quickly extract a certain line from the text. Or as tskuzzy already suggested, retrieve the complete text and split it yourself

Answer (score 1):

> How to get line 1 , 2 or .. etc?

Get the text from `JTextArea` / `JTextPane` by `JTextArea.getText()` / `JTextPane.getText()`. Once you have the text as string you can get the different lines by splitting the text with the new line character as a separator.

Answer (score 0):

```
JTextArea jText = new JTextArea("line1\nline2\nline3\nline4");

String temp = jText.getText();

String[] tempArr = temp.split("\n");
```

// Method to getText

```
public String getText(int lineNos){

             return Str[lineNos].getText();

}
```

// Method to setText

```
public void setText(int lineNos){

            Str[lineNos].setText("Hello");   // Can also use Scanner here

}
```